# ¿Cuál es la mejor forma de incrementar el monto de una suscripción con Checkout Personalizado de Mercadopago?

Tags: mercadopago

Nuestro **SAAS** tiene 4 tipos de planes que se cobran mensualmente.

Es muy normal que en medio de un mes, un cliente quiera hacer un *upgrade* de plan, por ejemplo, pasar de **$450** a **$1200**.

En este caso:

- ¿Cuál sería la forma que menos interacción del usuario requiera?
- ¿Se puede hacer sin necesidad de volver a pedirle los datos de tarjeta o el código de seguridad de la tarjeta?

Algunas ideas que teníamos era:

1. [Crear dinámicamente un plan](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/api-docs/custom-checkout/plans/) para cada usuario, y luego cambiarle el monto y descripción al plan.
2. Guardar las tarjetas (del lado de *MercadoPago*), y luego intentar cobrarle con la misma tarjeta. Pero puede ser que nos pida el código de seguridad de la tarjeta, por lo que [vimos en la documentación](https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/es/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/one-click-charges/javascript/).

¿Alguna idea mejor?

Comment: Hola @user1236654 bienvenido a Stack Overflow. Las suscripciones automática en la mayoría de estos casos toda la información de la tarjeta es guardada en su totalidad incluyendo el número de seguridad **CVV** / **CVC** así a la hora de actualizar o renovar las suscripciones serán automática sin pedir nuevamente los datos... Pero es recomendable avisar al cliente si desea o no guardar sus datos financieros para suscripciones automática.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

MercadoPago cuenta con una funcionalidad de creacion y actualización de suscripciones esto te permite hacer exactamente lo que necesitas, poder registrar una tarjeta de pago para hacer cobros recurrentes.

Con esto podrías :

- Registrar un usuario y asignarle un plan de suscripción.
- Crear diferentes planes dinamicamente.

Lo que es importante es que si no notificas al usuario los cambios de monto sin notificar al usuario, esto podría generar quejas de usuarios y quizas algun bloqueo desde MercadoPago.

Aqui la documentación relacionada:

https://www.mercadopago.com.ar/developers/en/solutions/payments/custom-checkout/plans-and-subscriptions/